# Is it possible to run a django pytest that has access to multiple databases, without executing the test against each database?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a Django project in which I'm trying to add a second database, however I'm having a hard time getting my existing test suite to cooperate.
I'm utilizing `django==3.2.16`, `pytest==6.2.2` along with `pytest-django==4.3.0`.

I seem to be running into two problems:

I'm seeing tests fail with an error like such

`AssertionError: Database queries to 'second' are not allowed in this test. Add 'second' to pytest_django.fixtures._django_db_fixture_helper.<locals>.PytestDjangoTestCase.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.`

From what I've found through issues and documentation is that I can do something like this to configure the test to have permission to the second db

`pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['default', 'second'])`

By having this at the top of my test file, it seems all the tests within have access to 'second', but this comes with the side effect that the test is now run TWICE, on each of the databases.

```
[gw0] [  2%] PASSED src/app/tests/test_some_stuff.py::test_case_1
[gw0] [  2%] ERROR src/app/tests/test_some_stuff.py::test_case_1
```

That is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I need the test to be run once, with access to both databases, and I can't seem to find an existing solution for this.

I just seem to be going in circles here...if I specify just one db the test fails because it doesn't have permission to access the second db. If I specify both, the first run succeeds and the other run fails. Is there a way I can just throw out the second run or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible to run a single test with access to both databases without having it run twice. When you specify multiple databases with `pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['default', 'second'])`, pytest-django will by default run the test for each database. But you can disable this behavior with a simple setting.

## Path 1

You should be able to achieve the desired behavior by making the following changes:

1. **Configure pytest to not run tests for each database**

   Update your `pytest` configuration (usually `pytest.ini` or `pyproject.toml`) with the following:

   ```ini
   [pytest]
   django_find_project = false
   addopts = --ds=myproject.settings
   databases = default second
   multi_db = true
   ```

   By setting `multi_db = true`, you allow Django to set up both databases for each test that uses the database, without running the test separately for each database.
2. **Add the `pytestmark` to your test file**

   You've already done this, but just for clarity:

   ```py
   pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['default', 'second'])
   ```

   This mark tells `pytest-django` that the test should be set up with access to both the `default` and `second` databases.

With these configurations, the test should be run only once, but it will have access to both the `default` and `second` databases.

## Path 2

1. **Create a custom pytest marker**:

   You can define a custom marker in your pytest configuration. Add this to your `pytest.ini`:

   ```ini
   [pytest]
   markers =
       dual_db: mark test as using both default and secondary databases
   ```
2. **Use the marker in your tests**:

   Mark the tests that need to use both databases with the new custom marker:

   ```py
   @pytest.mark.dual_db
   def test_some_function():
       # your test code here
   ```
3. **Customize Database Handling in `conftest.py`**:

   Add a file named `conftest.py` at the top level of your tests folder (if it doesn't already exist). Use it to customize pytest's behavior for tests marked with the custom `dual_db` marker:

   ```py
   import pytest
   from pytest_django.fixtures import _django_db_fixture_helper

   @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
   def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
       for item in items:
           if item.get_closest_marker(name="dual_db"):
               # Attach databases to the test
               setattr(item, 'databases', ['default', 'second'])

   @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
   def enable_db_access_for_dual_db(request):
       marker = request.node.get_closest_marker(name="dual_db")
       if marker:
           _django_db_fixture_helper(request, ['default', 'second'])
   ```

   This code will customize the test collection phase to check for tests marked with `dual_db`, and then it will set the `databases` attribute for those tests, allowing them to access both databases. The fixture `enable_db_access_for_dual_db` is automatically used for all tests because of the `autouse=True` argument and ensures that both databases are accessible.

With this setup, your tests marked with `@pytest.mark.dual_db` should only run once, but they'll have access to both databases.

Comment: I think I was a little too hasty in accepting....my apologies.
I thought it worked a couple of times initially but it seems that tests still run multiple times. From what I can tell multi_db has been deprecated for awhile, since django 2.2. Also I cannot get my tests to run if I try turning off the find_project flag and grabbing settings through addopts for some reason.

Comment: added secondary approach